# Why do the inequalities: 1) $x+2>-2/x$ and 2) $x^2 + 2x + 2 > 0$ have different number lines

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

The Question asks me to solve for $x$:

$$2^{(x+2)} > \left(\frac1{4}\right)^{(1/x)}$$

As it is an inequality I must find the domain.

By simplification I headed towards the equation $x+2 > -(2/x)$, after multiplying $x$ and then subtracting $2$ on both sides I get the following

$$x^2 + 2x + 2 > 0$$

When graphed, the number lines for $x$ look different for both. The first has '$x$ is an element of  $(0, \infty)$' and the later '$x$ is an element of Real Numbers.'

The answer is $x \in (0, \infty)$.

I suppose I must take the union here as there are multiple answers but why am I not allowed to multiply by x here?

I feel that I am missing a concept of inequalities that, 'multiplying by $x$ is forbidden', as I am self-studying this topic.

Comment: If you want to go down the road of multiplying both sides by $x$, then the equivalence that you have to use is $$A>\frac BC\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}CA>B\\ C>0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}CA<B\\ C<0\end{cases}$$ which isn't the thing that you've done.

Comment: Regarding why "multiplying by $x$" might be forbidden, how did you take into account that some values of $x$ are negative and that when you multiply by those values the direction of the inequality must be switched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing the principle that multiplication of an inequality by a negative quantity reverses the direction of an inequality.

So, for example, if you multiply the inequality by $x$ or an expression containing $x$ you must either know the sign of the expression or you must break the problem into two cases: one where the expression is positive and one where it is negative.

In this specific exercise, one can use an alternate approach of multiplying both sides by $x^2$ instead of $x$, since we know that $x^2>0$.

Note: We know that $x^2\ne0$ because of the $\frac{1}{x}$ term in the original statement of the problem.

\begin{eqnarray}
x+2&\gt& -\frac{2}{x}\\
x^2(x+2)&\gt&-2x\\
x^3+2x^2+2x&\gt&0\\x(x^2+2x+2)&\gt&0
\end{eqnarray}

Since $x^2+2x+2\gt0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the inequality is satisfied only for $x>0$.

Comment: Oh, I see!! Since x can be both negative and positive it modifies the domain. Multiplying by x^2, in that case, makes more sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, we can also proceed as follow

$$x+2 \gt -\frac{2}{x} \iff x+2+\frac2 x >0 \iff \frac{x^2+2x+2}{x}>0$$

and since $x^2+2x+2>0$ it reduces to $x>0$.